# How to approach rendering different instances of the same model from a dropdown selector?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking for ways to render information belonging to an instance of a model. Let's say a User has 5 different "Trading Account" instances of the TradingAccount model. From my Dashboard, if there is a dropdown selector menu where I can choose an instance of my Trading Account, I want it to render the information regarding "Trading Account A" and if I select "Trading Account B", then it renders the relevant information regarding "B".

The Dashboard should dynamically show the data depending on the selected instance of Trading Account. How do I render data from a specific instance of a model when a User selects an instance from a dropdown selector?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gmpj.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jvillian updated for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I would think of these as two different pages in a web app, or really N different pages where N is the number of different trading accounts.

You can then think of the pages that display the data as having URL paths like "/show/trading_account/12345", where 12345 is the ID of that account. More realistically it might be something like "/show/user/123/account/456", to indicate that you are showing account 456 for user with id 123.

As far as making the dropdown menu function, you would just need a bit of Javascript that can handle the mouseup event on the `<select>` element, and redirect the page to the appropriate URL that was discussed above. You might pair it with a mapping of display name to URL to open. So the javascript might look like:

```
function switchAccount() {
  var select = document.getElementById('account-select');
  var url = ACCOUNT_TO_URL[select.selectedOptions[0].value];
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

And the HTML might look like:

```
  <select id="account-select" onchange="switchAccount()">
    <option value="Account A">Account A</option>
    <option value="Account B">Account B</option>
  </select>
```